# Vim bad erb indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, eruby

When I tried to indent my .erb file via `gg=G`, I got this:

```
<li>
<%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
<%= link_to user.name, user %>
<% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
   | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
   <% end %>
   </li>
```

I've tried using vim-ruby, different eruby.vim files, to no avail. Does anyone have a eruby.vim indent file that actually works?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it. If removing `|`, or put `|` as a single line, everything works fine.

I suggest you follow this practice to make it as a single line when mixed with eruby code, or not to use `|` at all. Such thing is better to be CSS border.

Comment: Thanks. What about the fact that the erb tag under the <li> tag is not indented?

Comment: I tried to put a plain html div within `li`, it won't indent either.

Comment: indenting worked fine for me, without the `|` (using vim-ruby plugin)